# jQuery mobile finds elements from first page when on second page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've got a two page jQuery mobile app, and within the init function, the following code..

Call to the init function

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){
    MyPages.init();
});

init: function() {
    $('td[id$="drops"]').each(function() {
        console.log("Element: " + $(this).attr('id'));
    }),
};
```

I have elements in page one that match the above, such as '#early_drops', '#late_drops', etc. These elements do not exist on page 2, but when page 2 loads, the elements are displayed in the console just like when page 1 is loaded. What am I missing here?

Thanks very much,

-Adam vonNieda

Comment: In jquery mobile, you have everything loaded in a single page. It's just #tag change which does the navigation. So, you are getting the values of the old content which will be there in all the pages.

Comment: `$(document).on('pageinit', "#page_id", function(){` bind to a specific page, using page's `id`.

Comment: OK, that's what I was missing, thank you very much Omar!

Answer (score 0):

By default jQuery loads pages using AJAX into the existing page in order to allow the animated transitions.  If you don't want this you just need to 'turn off' the AJAX loading.

See description here: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/links/

> Links that point to other domains or that have rel="external", data-ajax="false" or target attributes will not be loaded with AJAX. Instead, these links will cause a full page refresh with no animated transition. Both attributes (rel="external" and data-ajax="false") have the same effect, but a different semantic meaning: rel="external" should be used when linking to another site or domain, while data-ajax="false" is useful for simply opting a page within your domain from being loaded via AJAX.

You can also disable AJAX across the entire app by default using global configuration: http://api.jquerymobile.com/global-config/